# DataType of InputField is double although in the PMMLPipeline it is string

Tags: scikit-learn, pmml

I am exporting a PMMLPipeline with a categorical string feature `day_of_week` as a `PMML` file. When I open the file in Java and list the `InputFields` I see that the data type of `day_of_week` field is double:

```
InputField{name=day_of_week, fieldName=day_of_week, displayName=null, dataType=double, opType=categorical}
```

Hence when I evaluate an input I get the error:

```
org.jpmml.evaluator.InvalidResultException: Field "day_of_week" cannot accept user input value "tuesday"
```

On the Python side the pipeline works with a string column:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[{"age": 10, "day_of_week": "tuesday"}])
y = trained_model.predict(X=data)
```

Miminal example for creating the PMML file:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data_dict = {
        'age': [1, 2, 3],
        'day_of_week': ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday'],
        'y': [5, 6, 7]
    }

    data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, columns=data_dict)

    numeric_features = ['age']
    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

    categorical_features = ['day_of_week']
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', categories='auto'))])

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('numerical', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
            ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

    pipeline = PMMLPipeline(
        steps=[
            ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
            ('classifier', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=60))])

    X = data.drop(labels=['y'], axis=1)
    y = data['y']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=30)

    trained_model = pipeline.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
    sklearn2pmml(pipeline=pipeline, pmml='RandomForestRegressor2.pmml', with_repr=True)
```

EDIT:
`sklearn2pmml` creates a PMML file with A DataDictionary with DataField "day_of_week" that has `dataType="double"`. I think it should be "String". Do I have to set the dataType somewhere to correct this?

```
<DataDictionary>
    <DataField name="day_of_week" optype="categorical" dataType="double">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assist SkLearn2PMML by providing "feature type hints" using `sklearn2pmml.decoration.CategoricalDomain` and `sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain` decorators (see [here](https://openscoring.io/blog/2020/02/23/sklearn_feature_specification_pmml/) for more details).

In the current case, you should prepend a `CategoricalDomain` step to the pipeline that deals with categorical features:

```
from sklearn2pmml.decoration import CategoricalDomain

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('domain', CategoricalDomain(dtype = str))
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', categories='auto'))
])
```

Comment: Ok, it works. Is there any preference of using `CategoricalDomain` over `OrdinalEncoder`? I was testing this: `('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder(categories='auto'))`

Comment: "Ordinal" means "Ordered Categorical". While days of week (Mon, Tue, Wed) can be regarded as ordinal, it's better to keep it simple and stick with categorical. Besides, the Scikit-Learn framework does not have the concept of ordinal features, so this extra details goes wasted anyway.

Comment: Hello, I am too working on this. I faced the same problem while applying `OrdinalEncoder` in the pipeline. The datatype="Double" was there as this stack suggests. And if this is the problem and if you need to use the `CategoricalDomain` as an extra step, then isn't this an issue already? In java it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply @user1808924.
The given solution works. Now, to add in his answer; I would like to note that `CategoricalDomain` **works for the single feature only**.

#### Problem:

So, when you use it in to pipeline like:

```py
# pipeline creatiion
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('domain', CategoricalDomain(dtype = str)),
    ('onehot', Ordinalecndoer())
])

# fit and transform of `df` with 3 features
categorical_transformer.fit_transform(df)

### >>> ERROR: Expected 1d array, got 2d array of shape (1000, 3)
```

Which means you will need to use *multiple* `CategoricalDomains` in there.

> **NOTE**: We often use it in the ColumnTransformer as well. You need to know how many categorical features are there before hand.

#### What can we do?

We will simply use the `MultiDomain` from the same library.

```py
from sklearn2pmml.decoration import MultiDomain

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('domain', MultiDomain([CategoricalDomain(dtype = str) for _ in range(3)])),
    ('onehot', OrdinalEncoder())
])
```

Note that the `3` is the number of categorical columns there. Hence, there will be `n` CategoricalDomains per categorical columns.

Then performing the transformation will work.